# How to update Progress Bar real time in VSTO Excel application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am having a small VSTO Excel add-in in which I am processing 1000s of rows and I want to show the progress bar when the user hits the button. Below is what I found on google, however, the progress bar is not updating in real-time. Can someone please help here? there are not much help on VSTO on google..

```
private void BtnApply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   FindDuplicate();
}

delegate void SetControlValueCallback(Control oControl, string propName, object propValue);

private void SetControlPropertyValue(Control oControl, string propName, object propValue)
{
   if (oControl.Dispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
   {
       SetControlValueCallback d = new SetControlValueCallback(SetControlPropertyValue);
       oControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { oControl, propName, propValue });
   }
   else
   {
       Type t = oControl.GetType();
       PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
       foreach (PropertyInfo p in props)
       {
           if (p.Name.ToUpper() == propName.ToUpper())
           {
               p.SetValue(oControl, propValue, null);
           }
       }
  }
}

public void FindDuplicate()
{
   pb.Maximum = objValues.GetUpperBound(0);

   for (int r = objValues.GetLowerBound(0); r <= objValues.GetUpperBound(0); r++)
   {
       ....... some opearation
       SetControlPropertyValue(pb, "value", r); 
   }
}
```